# Run Video Autoplay

Tags: kaltura

I want to add auto play to my 360 videos. Adding "autoplay=true" or "&autoplay=1" to the src is not helping.

```
 <div class="row Video-row">
                    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Content.VideoID))
                    {
                        if (!Model.Content.VideoID.Contains("youtube"))
                        {
                            <div class="Video-ratioPusher"></div>
                            <script src="http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/1960461/sp/196046100/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/@playerID/partner&autoplay=1_id/1960461?autoembed=true&entry_id=@Model.Content.VideoID&playerId=kaltura_player_@Model.Content.VideoID&cache_st=1459302170&maxwidth=0&maxheight=0&flashvars[streamerType]=auto&autoplay=1"></script>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <img class="Video-image" src="@Model.Content.BrandHtmlHelperExt.BrandAsset(this.Html, "images/player_logo_pink-480.png")" />
                            <div class="Video-ratioPusher"></div>    
                            <iframe class="kWidgetIframeContainer  kWidget.embed" src="@Model.Content.VideoID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change autoplay=1 to autoplay=true

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with flashvars:
flashvars[autoPlay] = true

Answer (score 0):

Add one more parameter to flashvars, like this:

```
  ...&maxheight=0&flashvars[streamerType]=auto&flashvars[autoPlay]=true"></script>
```